# URL validation error

Tags: jquery

I am validating the URL by using jQuery but it gives the following error

GET http://submitsitelink.com/checkurl.php?URL=http:%3A%2F%2Fgoo.com  302 Moved Temporarily 573ms

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get:
SELECT * FROM PLD_LINK_DEFINITION where URL='http:://goo.com'

Not that this is better, but it seems that there was a temporary error in the server

Comment: so no need to change the code or any other thing ? It will work after some time ?

Answer (score 0):

I get this when accessing the link:

```
  SELECT * FROM PLD_LINK_DEFINITION where URL='http:://goo.com'
```

Which is bad imo.